# How to do arithmetic operations on two data frames in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Dataframe 1

```
| A | B | C |
|---|---|---|
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

Dataframe 2

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
|---|---|
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 5 |
```

Result

```
| Col1 | Result |
|---|---|
| A | 0 |
| B | 1|
| C | -2|
```

The value in col2(dataframe2) is subtracted from the row value in column A(dataframe1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can transpose dataframe1 then do inner join with dataframe2 to proceed with arithmetic operation.

```
from pyspark.sql import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").getOrCreate()

# Sample dataframes
df1 = spark.createDataFrame([(1, 2, 3)], "A int, B int, C int")
df2 = spark.createDataFrame([("A", 1), ("B", 1), ("C", 5)], "col1 string, col2 int")

# To transpose df1
# df1 = df1.selectExpr("stack(3, 'A', A, 'B', B, 'C', C) as (c1, c2)")
# Dynamic stack expression 
stack_expression = ''.join(list(map(lambda c: f"'{c}',{c},", df.columns)))[:-1]
stack_expression = f"stack({len(df.columns)}, {stack_expression}) as (c1, c2)"

df.selectExpr(stack_expression)

out_df = df1.join(df2, df1.c1 == df2.col1, 'inner').drop("c1")

out_df.selectExpr("col1", "c2 - col2 result").show()

+----+------+
|col1|result|
+----+------+
|   B|     1|
|   C|    -2|
|   A|     0|
+----+------+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! For a 100 columns where I cannot mention all the column name, what would be the best way to perform this?

Comment: Updated the answer, Please check.